# VPN on debian based router

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

My work includes doing MITM analyses and since clients cannot always be made proxy aware, I have resorted to a transparent proxy setup.

In more detail, I took an old laptop and wifi modem which I put into bridge-mode, installed debian 9 and connected to my main network / WAN over the wireless interface. The wifi modem in bridge mode is connected to the ethernet interface which acts as the gateway for the client and I forward all traffic from it to the wireless interface.

This router also takes care of DNS using bind9.

It looks like this:

```
Client (10.0.0.12) - > eth0 (10.0.0.1) - > wlan0 (192.168.178.40) - > WAN (192.168.178.1)
                      |                                          |
                      |           DEBIAN BASED ROUTER            |
                      |__________________________________________|
```

And when used as transparent proxy, I use the following iptable rules to redirect traffic to a listener on port 8888:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s0 -p tcp --dport 80  -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s0 -p tcp --dport 443  -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`

Looking like this:

```
                               -> MITM LISTENER (:8888) ->
                              |                           |
                        port 80, 443                      |
                              |                           |
Client (10.0.0.12) - > eth0 (10.0.0.1) - > wlan0 (192.168.178.40) - > WAN (192.168.178.1)
                      |                                          |
                      |           DEBIAN BASED ROUTER            |
                      |__________________________________________|
```

Ok, with that visualized, I am looking for a way to connect to the internet over VPN and not over my own public IP while still being able to perform a MITM.

I was looking at OpenVPN, but am overall uncertain how to configure this setup.

Comment: Whether traffic leaves through `wlan0` or `tun0` doesn’t matter at all though...?

Comment: @DanielB all that matters is that my public IP for the traffic sent is different. This is to deal with country blockages on the client (10.0.0.12) but while we will still be able to capture traffic with the MITM (192.168.178.40:8888)

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you are asking. I suspect the answer lies with policy based routing and treating stuff originating from the box differently to data going through it by pushing it through a different routing table.

Comment: I don’t see any need for policy routing. With the OpenVPN connection active, traffic is simply passed through there instead of `wlan0`, all with regular routing. There should be no need whatsoever for special configurations. Just sign up with some VPN provider, follow their guide, the end.